# Send email by `mailx` is not working for some email domain

Tags: email, gmail, centos7, mailx, ssmtp

I'm am trying to send a email from centos 7 with the google ssmtp settings.
I just installed `mailx` and `ssmtp` and I am trying to make it work.

When I send a email to for example gmail; it arrives like it should, but when I send a email to a localdomain, the email isn’t received.

What could be the problem of this. 
Does this mean my ip is blocked of the localip.

How can I make sure to send emails for all domains?

This is my test mail command.

```
echo "test mail body(`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`)" | mailx -v -s "test mail subject(`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`)"  mymail@gmail.com  mymail@companymail.jp
```

Thank you!